# How to use Google Drive File Picker with Apps Script HTML Service

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Does anyone have any samples of using [Google Drive FilePicker](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) with Apps Script [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/). Is it even possible?

I'd like to use it to select files or upload files from Drive using AppsScript HTML Service.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it isn't possible to use it in HtmlService, due to Caja restrictions. We're working on enabling it, but it may take some time.

**Edit** As of March 2014 this is now possible. See [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs) for sample code.

Answer (score 2):

You can upload files to your drive with the following HTML, client side JavaScript, and .gs server side JavaScript.

### HTML

```
<form class='frmUpload'>
  <input name="picOneUpload" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="picUpload(this.parentNode, 'a')" ><label id='lblPicLoadA'>Pick a Picture To Upload!</label>
</form>
```

### JavaScript - in HTML Script tag

```
<script>
  window.picUpload = function(frmData) {
  //console.log("picUpload ran: " + frmData);
   
  google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure)
    .withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)
    .uploadPic(frmData)
  };
</script>
```

### Code.gs

```
function uploadPic(argBlobInput) {
  var uploadedBlob = argBlobInput["picOneUpload"];
  var fldrSssn = DriveApp.getFolderById('Your Folder ID');
  fldrSssn.createFile(uploadedBlob );
};
```