# Upload to a specific folder in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-drive-api

So I want to make a form upload file, photos, videos to a specific folder (file, photos, videos) in Google Drive, but I don't know how to make that in Google Apps Script. I tried like this and error in console "invalid argument listener".

So here is a index

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <title>Upload Files</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  </head> 
  <body>
    <h1>File Uploader</h1>
    <div id="form" style="text-align:center;display:block">
    <form>
        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="myFile" mulitple>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div>
          <h3>Choose Folder to upload</h3>
          <h6>Max. 50MB</h6>
          <input class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="submitBtn1" value="File">
          <input class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="submitBtn2" value="Foto">
          <input class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="submitBtn3" value="Video">
        </div>  
        <label id="resp"></label>
    </form>
    </div>
    <script>
      document.getElementById('submitBtn1').addEventListener('click',
        function(e){
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).uploadFiles(this.childNode)
        })

        function onSuccess(data_files){
          document.getElementById('resp').innerHTML = "File Uploaded succesful";
        }

      document.getElementById('submitBtn2').addEventListener('click',
        function(e){
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).uploadPhotos(this.childNode)
        })

        function onSuccess(data_photos){
          document.getElementById('resp').innerHTML = "Photo Uploaded succesful";
        }

      document.getElementById('submitBtn3').addEventListener('click',
        function(e){
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).uploadVideos(this.childNode)
        })

        function onSuccess(data_videos){
          document.getElementById('resp').innerHTML = "Video Uploaded succesful";
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this a code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  return html.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}


function uploadFiles(data_files)
{
 var file = data_files.myFile;
 var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('12gKxEtiZhL0hKU6qd-ngVih1DhP_UV8_');
 var createFile = folder.createFile(file);
 return createFile.getUrl();
}

function uploadPhotos(data_photos)
{
 var file = data_photos.myFile;
 var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1LngD6Ziqqd2i5mt-IGX3NWzVPMIAJEWU');
 var createFile = folder.createFile(file);
 return createFile.getUrl();
}

function uploadVideos(data_videos)
{
 var file = data_videos.myFile;
 var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1LJgcCAn1_Kb6SVVLfxzKkmiw_hg47zoP');
 var createFile = folder.createFile(file);
 return createFile.getUrl();
}
```

If required method If Else, sorry please tell me how to make that, I'm still learn about coding

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Google Drive File Picker with Apps Script HTML Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530287/how-to-use-google-drive-file-picker-with-apps-script-html-service)

Comment: unfortunately no, that code just one folder, not specific folder

Comment: Regardless  note how that answer sends the form itself.

Answer (score 1):

I have not reviewed your code in deep, there is an error on the parameter of the google.run.script statements. `this.childNode` is returning `undefined`.

In order to send the "form data" to the server side code, replace it by the form node, i.e. add the following in the `<script>`, above the functions:

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
```

then, replace `this.childNode` in the `script.google.run` statements, i.e.

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).uploadFiles(form)
```

By "form data" I mean that you have to pass the form element as the parameter of the server side function. The above statement assigns the form element (`<form>...</form>`) to the `form` variable. `google.script.run` will use the FormData interface to build an object having a property for each form data entry element (`<input>`, `<select>`, etc.) using their name attributes as the property name, and the element value as the property value.

Related

- [Error when <input type="file"> is blank on a submitted form (Google App Script)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28904746/1595451)
- [Uploading Multiple Files to Google Drive with Google App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31126181/1595451)

Resources

- [Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)
- [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)
- [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node)

Comment: can you tell me more about that? replace to "childNode" for function form data?

Comment: @RobertFila Added links to some resources that might help you.

Comment: Added explanation of "form data"